# Reverse proxy HTTPS to HTTP wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, url-routing, wildfly, reverse-proxy

I am writing a Java application with following requirements
I have a client which communicates with wildfly server on port 9000 using https but now I have nodejs added on port 9001 and I want to redirect all https calls made to  node.js localhost through wildfly. This redirection requires https to HTTP conversion.

Example:
`https:/abc.com:9000/getInfo` should be redirected to `http:/localhost:9001/getInfo`

I configured my wildfly to reverse-proxy but unfortunately it does not redirect.
It still gives me information from  `https:/abc.com:9000/getInfo`  and does not redirect

P.S I don't want to use third-party tools like apache, nginx, squid or pound I want wildfly to handle redirection from https to http is this possible?

I ran this commands from my JBoss-cli and restarted my server but no luck

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=my-handler:add()
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=remote-host1/:add(host=localhost, port=9001) 
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/reverse-proxy=my-handler    
/host=host1:add(outbound-socket-binding=remote-host1, scheme=ajp, instance-id=myroute, path=/getInfo)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location=\   /getInfo:add(handler=my-handler)
```

Comment: Running into same problem - did you get it working?